# No puedo exportar el apk desde android

Tags: java, android-studio, apk

[image: Error al exportar]

Estoy tratando de expotar el apk pero me arroja el siguiente error Could not download lint-checks-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.0.1): No cached version available for offline mode

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje:

> No cached version available for offline mode

Indica que debes desactivar el "modo offline" para que baje una versión del .jar que necesitas para generar tu proyecto.

Desde el menú principal ve a `View` > `Tool Windows` > `Gradle`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]